# Do I need to create an index on the column which is used by SUM(col)?

Tags: mysql, sql

Please take a look at this:

```
SELECT SUM(col1) FROM mytable WHERE col2 = :val2
```

What index(s) do I need for query above? I mean `col1` needs an index because it is used in `SUM()` function?

Also as a note, what about `COUNT()` function?

Comment: `col1` **doesn't** need an index. Indexes in databases function exactly like indexes in books (those paper thingies in real life). Index is a data structure that's kept in memory (usually) and it tells the database where a piece of information resides on the hard drive. That's why you often index columns that appear in `WHERE` condition. However, to avoid seeking on the disk, you can create a compound index just like Gordon Linoff suggested. That way, MySQL finds all the records that satisfy `col2 = :val` and then it avoids seeking on the disk since `col1` is part of the index so it reads it.

Answer (score 1):

The best index for this query is `mytable(col2, col1)`.  It is a covering index for the query.

The logic for the columns in a query starts with the `WHERE` and `ON` clauses.  MySQL has pretty good [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) about constructing indexes for variable conditions.

Comment: Ah ok, just what index is the best for [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0b2b48e8f6ea7dd2a6e7e53e521f0b29)?